# $ git format-patch -n and $ git format-patch HEAD~n

Tags: git, format-patch

I’ve noticed there’re some differences between

```
$ git format-patch –n
```

and

```
$ git format-patch HEAD~n
```

According to the documentation: 
*“-n Prepare patches from the topmost  commits.”* 
So I think these two commands should lead to the same result. But actually they’re not, especially when n is large, say 10 or 20, and in a source that exists plenty of merges. Could somebody provide any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's `-<n>` in my (1.8.3.3) git man page, vs `-n` which is short for `--num`.  I assume you mean you're running `git format-patch -12` vs `git format-patch HEAD~12`?  (The exact text of the construction is important!)

Comment: I tried this out on a test repo, `format-patch` seems to ignore merge commits.